# Download zip file from a url

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a URL that, when submitted in a web browser, pops up a dialog box to save a zip file. I wrote the following code to download the file, but the file is always empty. I try a lot of things and nothing. Someone could help?

```
def download_files(url):
    
    download = requests.get(url)
    open(f"prestacao_de_contas_eleitorais_candidatos_2022.zip", "wb").write(download.content)

url = "https://cdn.tse.jus.br/estatistica/sead/odsele/prestacao_contas/prestacao_de_contas_eleitorais_candidatos_2022.zip"

current_dir = os.getcwd()

# criteria to download only once
if len(os.listdir(current_dir)) == 0:
    download_files(url)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: What is the URL that contains link to this ZIP file?

Comment: @AndrejKesely it is defined in his code. The 'url' variable.

Comment: We need to see more of your code. This isn't enough to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman No, I mean the web page that has the link to the zip file URL.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The website is this: https://dadosabertos.tse.jus.br/dataset/dadosabertos-tse-jus-br-dataset-prestacao-de-contas-eleitorais-2022/resource/e45493d5-75df-4ccf-a4b4-7b1f5213577d. The url link is pinned right down in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Set `stream=True` in your `requests.get` call and add a useragent header to your request

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://cdn.tse.jus.br/estatistica/sead/odsele/prestacao_contas/prestacao_de_contas_eleitorais_candidatos_2022.zip"

download = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    with open("zip.zip", 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in download.iter_content():
            file.write(chunk)
```